# IOS Swift how can I do this button and textfield design?

Tags: ios, swift, button, label, textfield

I am beginner on swift. I see this design in many applications as button, label, and textfield and i wanna add this design to my app. How can I design a button and text areas same as photo? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please take the Stack Overflow [tour] and review [ask]. You need to do a little work first... read up on auto-layout... search for examples... try some things out. If you run into a ***specific*** problem, come back and ask about that.

Comment: I'd recommend investigating `UITableView`

Comment: @AdamPro13 thanks but its not tableview :(

Comment: Yes, this is a table view with table view cells that have one label on the left side and another label on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a UITableView.
There are a lot of solutions. Here are two of them:
1. We can use UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: "cell") (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell?language=objc).
2. Or you can create own cell. Add labels, constraints and “play” with hugging priority.